# Ajax + Html 5 History Api

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, html5-history-api, php

Здравствуйте. 
Допустим есть несколько страниц, почти идентичные друг другу(различны только контент и комментарии к нему):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!---Header-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            Контент 1
            Комментарии к контенту 1
        </div>
        <aside>
         <!---Правый блок -->
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

Отличие других страниц только в:

```
    <div id="content">
        Контент 2
        Комментарии к контенту 2
    </div>
```

и т.д.

Нужно сделать так чтобы при переходе не загружалась новая страница полностью, а только этот кусочек(Контенет 2 , Комментарии к контенту 2).

Пробовал использовать XMLHttpRequest, но при этом в div id="content", загружалась новая страница полностью (с header'ом, футером, и правым блоком).

Так же пробовал через 
`$("#content").load(url + " #content");` 
всё вроде бы работало, но с большими задержками(то есть после нажатия на ссылку для перехода на вторую страницу, была задержка секунды 2-3)

Со сменой адреса(history.pushState) проблем нет, а вот с навигационными кнопками браузера проблема: ссылка менялась, а содержимое нет (думаю, что если правильно реализовать первый шаг, то этот рабочим само собой)

Как это можно реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пересказывать всё не вижу смысла, поэтому, если время есть, то [почитайте эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/), если время ограничено, то переходим по [этой ссылке](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API). Прокрутите страницу вниз - там мануал на русском языке.

P.S. И вот еще [демо от автора](http://history.spb-piksel.ru/)

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Можете посмотреть как об этом писал я: http://plutov.by/post/html5_history_api